# How to track email address who logged in Gmail in their browser?

Tags: session, cookies, gmail-api, browser-cache

I want to get an email address from GMail account for the below case:

1. User logged with their GMAIL((https://www.gmail.com) credential in a Browser(Chrome/Firefox)
2. After logged in, they might be browse different sites.
3. If they browse our website, we have to track the user's email id when they logged in.

Is it possible to get it?

I know this is almost hacking, but I want to get it by legally. So, Is there Google provide for that anyway like API or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only legal way to get the email address for a user that browses to your web site is to **ask the user for it**.  (At least in most countries).

Furthermore, Google API policies require:

> You will comply with all applicable privacy laws and regulations
>   including those applying to PII. You will provide and adhere to a
>   privacy policy for your API Client that clearly and accurately
>   describes to users of your API Client what user information you
>   collect and how you use and share such information (including for
>   advertising) with Google and third parties.

See:  https://developers.google.com/terms/